# How to output a function with numeric inputs evaluated?

Tags: matlab, function

I have

```
a= 3; b=-2; c= 2; d=-2;
fprintf( 'a=%.0f b=%.0f c=%.0f d=%.0f\n', a, b, c, d );
f = @(t,y) [(a*y(1) + b*y(2)); (c*y(1) + d*y(2))];
```

I want to display f with a,b,c,d replaced by 3,-2,2,-2

```
f = @(t,y) [(3*y(1) - 2*y(2)); (2*y(1) - 2*y(2))];
```

The function works properly in later code. How to do?

Thank you. MM

Comment: What exaclty you mean by display the function. Do you want to display the values the function displays for an example input?

Comment: please see edited post.

Comment: btw your function is independent of `t`. So `t` serves no purpose here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not 100% sure if I understand your question correctly, but usually you can do something like that with the functionality of the Matlab Symbolic Toolbox. Use the `syms` function of this toolbox to create symbolic variables, and then use the `subs` function of the toolbox, which allows you to replace the symbolic variables with your numeric values.

So let's say: a, b, c, and d are syms, defined by

> `syms a b c d`. You'd do `subs(f, [a b c d], [3 -2 2 -2])`

Hope that helps. Should at least point you in the correct direction.